# Authenticating with PHP to a Radius Server

Tags: php

I have been ask to created a login script in PHP that would authentication user information against a Radius server. I have the IP, Secret Phrase and Port number for the Radius Server.

When I started to try and authenticate my account I received some debug notification.

1. Added Attribute 1 (User-Name), format S, value *****
2. Added Attribute 2 (User-Password), format S, value *****
3. Added Attribute 6 (Service-Type), format I, value *****

As I was looking thru my PHP extension and I do not see a DLL for Radius. Is there a specific URL in which I can download the PHP_radius.dll extension?

Comment: Which platform are you working on windows, linux, osx, ... ?

Comment: I am using Windows 2008R2